# XMLHttpRequest cannot load error When we have GeoServer and WebServer on same domain

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, wfs, http-headers

I have Geoserver and webserver on same domain (Windows XP with IIS). But when i tried to get WMS feature info, i got this error in chrome. If Geoserver and webserver on same orgin, no need of proxy i think. so please suggest me to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?LAYERS=cite%3Aplym_p1_examplec…e%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fvnd.ogc.gml&SRS=EPSG%3A27700&X=596&Y=160. Origin http://localhost:3890 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 2):

The port is considered part of the site so `http://localhost:3890` and `http://localhost:8080` are not the same. From the first paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

> In computing, the same-origin policy is an important security concept for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site – a combination of **scheme, hostname, and port number**[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) – to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) Same-origin policy also applies to XMLHttpRequest and to robots.txt.[2]